# How to prevent people from scrolling using mouse wheel press our touch dragging?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, touch

In HTML/CSS/JS, there is one thing I am having trouble figuring out:
How to prevent people from scrolling an element using the mouse wheel press (i.e. hold down the mouse wheel and drag, or click the mousewheel, drag, click the mouse wheel again) and how to do the same when people try to drag the elements around on a touch-device.

This is something I stumble upon, amongst other places, when trying to make a hamburger-style menu.

Setting an element's CSS to *overflow: hidden* will hide the scroll bars, but using above two methods, it is still easy to scroll through them.
Until now, the only 'solution' I found was to make a second element, and position it on top of the element that should not be scrollable. But this hardly seems like a perfect solution to me.

- How can these events be captured using JavaScript?
- How can, on, for instance, [this page](http://www.ymc.ch/sandbox/hamburger/mobile-menu-demo.html), scrolling horizontally and vertically be blocked when the menu is open?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a jsfiddle, we can give a better solution. If you are OK with jquery, I can give some solution for your second point "How can, on, for instance, this page, scrolling horizontally and vertically be blocked when the menu is open?".

First you need to create one simple class like below.

```
.overhidden
{
 overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Next, we need to apply this class when you press the menu icon on your screen. Also we need to remove if they click again for closing. It is easy to do in jquery like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hamburger').click(function(){
      $('body').toggleClass('overhidden');
   });
 });
```