# Is there a way to prevent user scrolling from pressing the scroll wheel and dragging?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to prevent user scrolling from pressing the scroll wheel and dragging?

I have a site that uses the scroll wheel and gestures to navigate through the page, but this dragging motion with the scroll wheel does not activate, is there a way to prevent this from scrolling the body?

Thanks

Checked chatgpt with no avail

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234990/how-to-prevent-people-from-scrolling-using-mouse-wheel-press-our-touch-dragging) can help, it uses jQuery though

Comment: https://astoncm.com/ do this really well, they have somehow disabled the scroll wheel button and only allow scroll